# Using subselect in join to update table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update a table with column aliases using a subselect. The problem is that when I add an inner join, the script breaks:

This update works, but there's no inner join with the subselect:

```
declare @erase table
(
id varchar(10),
total int
)
insert into @erase (id) select 'x'

declare @var1 int = 10
declare @var2 int = 10
declare @var3 int = 10
declare @var10 int = 10
declare @var11 int = 10
declare @var12 int = 10

update @erase 
set id = num / den
FROM
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den'
) as innerTable
```

But it breaks when I add a `join`:

```
declare @erase table
(
id varchar(10),
total int
)
insert into @erase (id) select 'x'

declare @var1 int = 10
declare @var2 int = 10
declare @var3 int = 10
declare @var10 int = 10
declare @var11 int = 10
declare @var12 int = 10

update @erase 
set id = innerTable.num / innertable.den
from @erase inner join innertable on
@erase.id = innertable.id
FROM
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den'
) as innerTable
```

I wanted to use a `cte`, but I would need an additional repository for the `num / den`. The following will not work:

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den',
    num / den as 'total' -- will break
)
update @erase 
set total = cte.total
from @erase inner join cte on
@erase.id = cte.id
```

How can I update `@erase` in the same transaction where the `num / den` is generated?

Edit:
I found workaround, but I still can't update with final value 'total':

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den',
    num / den as 'total' -- will break
)
update @erase 
set total = num / den --Although I prefer using alias total.
from @erase inner join cte on
@erase.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this sample:

```
update @erase 
set id = innerTable.num / innertable.den
from @erase inner join innertable on
@erase.id = innertable.id
FROM
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den'
) as innerTable
```

The problem here is there are **two FROM clauses**. You can fix it by specifying `innertable` inline, like this:

```
update @erase 
set id = innerTable.num / innertable.den
from @erase 
inner join (
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as num,
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as den
) innertable on @erase.id = innertable.id
```

Then there's the CTE version:

```
with cte as
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as 'num',
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as 'den',
    num / den as 'total' -- will break
)
```

The problem here is `num` and `den` on the `total` line don't exist as usable names yet. You can fix this several ways, but one option is layering the queries in multiple CTEs:

```
with cte1 as
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as num,
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as den,
), 
cte2 As (
    select *,  num/den as total from cte1
)
update @erase 
set total = cte2.total
from @erase 
inner join cte2 on @erase.id = cte2.id
```

Another option is repeating the expressions:

```
with cte as
(
    select 
    'x' as id,
    @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 as num,
    @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 as den,
    ( @var1 * @var2 * @var3 * @var10* @var11* @var12 )
      / 
    ( @var1 + @var2 + @var3 + @var10+ @var11+ @var12 ) as total
)
update @erase 
set total = cte.total
from @erase 
inner join cte on @erase.id = cte.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much.